# install_referrer mail from google

Tags: android, flutter, install-referrer

I've received a mail from google regarding install_referrer

> We recently announced that we’ll be deprecating the install_referrer
>   intent broadcast mechanism. Because one or more of your apps uses this
>   intent to track referrals, we wanted to ensure you make the switch
>   before March 1, 2020. After this date, new versions of the Play Store
>   app will no longer broadcast the install_referrer intent after app
>   installs.

The plugins I'm using in my project

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
device_info: "^0.2.1"
shared_preferences:"^0.4.2"
flutter_webview_plugin: "0.3.10+1"
connectivity: "0.4.4"
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.0"
image_picker: "0.6.1+4"
flutter_html_view: "^0.3.1"
firebase_messaging: "5.1.5"
flutter_web_browser: "0.11.0"
flutter_custom_tabs: "^0.6.0"
```

Tried searching install_referrer in my project unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [firebase_messaging plugin](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire), this probably has an outdated version of the [install_referrer dependency](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1594).